# Share virtual environment

Tags: desktop-environments, virtualenv

I have a setup python virtual environment (virtualenv). I know that with virtualenv a new directory is created, where all dependencies and libraries for my python version are stored. Is it possible to share the directory/virtual environment , so that I can run the same virtual environment on a different machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the virtual environments are stored (hidden) in your home directory. Simply copy the folder related to the virtal environment to your other computer or sync the folder using rsyncd to avoid having several different versions.

The virtual environment folders can be found in ~/.virtualenvs on a standard Ubuntu installation.